# TypeError - Missing required positional arguments using getattr

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am receiving a string which has multiple arguments. When I pass the strings individually to the function I am able to get this to work. I am trying to see if there is a way to get the commented line below to work.

```
testc.py
class TestClass(object):

    def test(k1, k2, k3, d1):
        print(k1,k2,k3)
        return 'done'
```

```
from testc import TestClass

args = 'earth,moon,mars'
d = {'key':'value'}    
#v = getattr(TestClass, 'test')(args, d) #how do I get this to work?
v = getattr(TestClass, 'test')("earth", "moon", "mars", d)
print(v)
```

Comment: The below answers will solve your problem, but here are some other notes: conventionally, one should call the constructor instead of using `getattr`, and the first arg of the function `test` should be `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to turn your string into a list: `args_list = args.split(",")`.

Then you have to unpack that list using `*` to pass the list content as separate parameters( w/o the `*` the list would be passed as a single parameter).

```
class TestClass(object):
    def test(k1, k2, k3, d1):
        print(k1,k2,k3)
        return 'done'

args = 'earth,moon,mars'
d = {'key':'value'}
args_list = args.split(",")
print("args_list:", args_list)
v = getattr(TestClass, 'test')(*args_list, d)
print("v:", v)
```

Output:

```
args_list: ['earth', 'moon', 'mars']
earth moon mars
v: done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` to split the string into a list, and then use `*` to spread them into separate arguments.

```
arglist = args.split(',');
v = getattr(TestClass, 'test')(*arglist, d)
```